# TinyMCE Skins, Better than the

Tags: javascript, layout, tinymce, skin

Are there better looking TinyMCE skins except the one of http://thebigreason.com/ and http://www.cirkuit.net/projects/tinymce/cirkuitSkin/?

I couldn't find one that has:

1. buttons for ALL features
2. a nice layout

Comment: I posted a new version of thebigreason skin on May 14, 2012 with some nicer looking dialogs cleaner layout with multiple toolbars. No new buttons yet, though. I’ll attempt to tackle that in the next release. The famfamfam icons I use don’t match up to everything tinymce does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no other skins out there with buttons for all features. Well, a nice layout depends on the point of view.
I suggest you develop your own skin according to your needs.